# Flutter web PWA offline support for images, audio files, video files etc

Tags: flutter, progressive-web-apps, flutter-web

I would like to create a Flutter Web PWA which downloads all the necessary content when the PWA home page loads, so even if the user goes offline the content would be available, is this possible?

Comment: It is possible, just add a folder with your images to assets in pubspec.yaml, flutter will do the rest.

Comment: But the content is coming for the internet, it should be fetched.